# Visual Studio 2008 Output - Hide dll loads and unloads

Tags: visual-studio-2008, panel

Visual Studio automatically displays dll loads/unloads in its output panel, like so:

```
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll'
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdsapi.dll'
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wldap32.dll'
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll'
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll'
'DialogAppDEBUG.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemcomn.dll'
```

Is there anyway to temporarily disable this?  When doing extensive debugging via DebugOutputString(), those messages always tend to push my prints off the panel and I have to search around for them, making the process much more cumbersome.  I've Googled and searched through all of the VS options I could think of, but to no avail...

Comment: Not sure it's possible, unless there's a hidden registry key somewhere. Def. not in the settings =(

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Asked the same thing today, and the answer was as simple as:

> Right click in the Output window when
>   you're running your program and
>   uncheck all of the messages you don't
>   want to see (like Thread Exit
>   messages).

In your case, uncheck "Module Load messages"

Comment: THANK YOU!  That's it!  Can't believe I couldn't find that...sometimes the answer is in the most obvious place, but for some reason it didn't seem to be documented anywhere :)

Comment: @Metal450: things that you have to right-click and guess they may be in some hidden popup menu aren't in the most obvious place... I got here searching the same. And the same apllies to Visual Studio 2010's "Show IntelliSense errors" on the errors window.

Comment: By the way, it's not necessary to actually run the program in order to get that popup menu - just switch the Output window's context from `Build` to `Debug` and you can do the same thing.