# How to eliminate 'MyApp.vshost.exe: Loaded some.dll' messages in vstudio output window

Tags: visual-studio, output-window

Is it possible to eliminate messages similar to the one in the title? I get too many 'Loaded ... .dll' lines in the Visual Studio Output window and I'd like to see only those relevant to me (exceptions, traces).

My project is a WPF application and i'm using VS2013 but I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270001/visual-studio-2008-output-hide-dll-loads-and-unloads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the Output window and uncheck "Module Load Messages" and "Module Unload Messages" options.