# Debugging is not working properly in visual studio on my laptop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have problem about debugging in visual Studio 2010. when i start C# project file and compiling the C# source file or Window form then it is showing the stack trace on output console. You can see the image at last. I checked on google,youtube but i didn't get the proper solution for it. same problem had occured on visual studio 2012.It is properly works the without debug mode. it is having a problem with debug mode..so Please give me solution..

[image]

Comment: That is not the stacktrace, those are the loaded modules if you want to disable them look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270001/visual-studio-2008-output-hide-dll-loads-and-unloads)

Comment: whats your problem being modules getting loaded as long as you are able to hit breakpoint into vs.

Comment: 0xc000041d = STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION = An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback . add better exception handling in code

Comment: I am not able to debug the program.It is directly terminating. if i use the breakpoints then there is also having the same problem. is it problem related to .net framework.?

Answer (score 0):

This is the module list. Works as designed. It is not an error.